# Z-Score for Sum of Proportions?

Tags: proportion, z-score, sum

First, please bear with me. I am not very savvy with statistics, so I may be mixing up terms or using things improperly. Second, I am dealing with statistics related to baseball, so let me explain those stats first. If you are a baseball fan and know how OBP, SLG, and OPS work, then feel free to skip this next section.

---

The stat I am most concerned with right now is OPS (on-base plus slugging). This itself is simply the sum of OBP (on-base percentage) and SLG (slugging percentage). OBP is *basically* found by dividing the number of times a batter reaches base by their plate-appearances, PA's (the number of times they come up to the plate). Slugging is similar, but only accounts for hits, gives different hits different weights, and divides by at-bats, AB's (which is itself a subset of PA's).

OBP = (H + BB + HBP) / PA

SLG = (1*1B +  2*2B + 3*3B + 4*HR) / AB

OPS = OBP + SLG

---

So OPS is the sum of OBP and SLG, each with a different sample size. Possibly important to note: 1 at-bat counts as 1 plate-appearance, but 1 plate-appearance is not necessarily 1 at-bat. I.e., they are not independent. As far as I know, one can determine a z-score for a proportion using the formula:
z = (p - p_0) / sqrt(p_0 (1 - p_0) / n). In the case of OPS, what would n, the sample size, be? Is this even a tractable question? For all I know, I could be using z-scores in a completely improper way.

Ultimately, I have 2 issues:

1. OPS can sometimes be greater than 1. This would result in a non-real z-score which, well... doesn't make sense, right? In general, is there a method for determining the deviation from the mean for a ratio, where that ratio can be less than or greater than 1?
2. How can I (if it's even possible using this kind of method) get a z-score for OPS, when it's the sum of 2 proportions, each with different sample sizes? What would the sample size be for this kind of thing? Is there a better way to determine the deviation from normal for OPS, or sums-of-proportions in general?